# Page specific roles on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We are a College of Higher Education that offers a range of undergraduate, postgraduate and short courses to individuals both in the UK and oversees. We want to empower programme leaders and other staff members to have control over the content on the pages that are relevant to their positions.

For example, for the Bachelor of Science in Business Studies page, we want the programme leader to ONLY have access to this page and to be able to edit the content. For the Campus Ministries page, we want the Chaplain to ONLY have access to this page and to be able to edit the content. When editing, they need to be able to add pictures, writing, upload files, etc.

However, we want there to be a stage whereby when an edit is made, it doesn't go live straight away but needs to be approved by an admin. The admin needs to be notified as soon as the edit is made and he/she needs to be able to approve/disapprove or make edits to what the programme leader did before approving. Eg. if the Bachelor of Science in Business Studies programme leader adds a new picture, the admin needs to be notified. If he sees that it's a good addition but a wrong picture, then the admin needs to have access to change the photo and then approve the updated changes.

**Just to recap, this is the workflow I'm aiming for:**

- Editors can only edit only pages asigned to them
- Editors can save the new content but not publish it
- Admin is notified to approve the changes (or make any edits, if necessary)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins available to allow granular control over what a user can and cannot do, but out of the box it is not possible with WordPress.

Adding the edit_pages capability to the contributor role using the members plugin gets it pretty close, but not quite where you need to go.

Certainly possible, but would take some tinkering by a professional to get it all right and not open up security holes in your permissions setup.